# Windows Phone , Install time method call

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any way that we can call a method only once in the entire life of the application.
For Ex : If i want to display a terms and conditions screen.

If the user agrees, then for the entire life of the application, the screen should not be displayed there after.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You could simply write to a file indicating that this step has been taken.

Comment: You mean , i should write it to a file outside the application context or ?

Comment: take a look at isolated storage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626522(v=vs.92)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Isolated storage settings did the trick for me here :).

Comment: Jim O'Neil : Could you kindly put your comment as an answer so that i can accept it ?